# Disambiguate the [period] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The usage guidance for the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/period) is surprisingly vague:

> A period of time is an interval, a span of time. You can also use it
> for questions related to the actual punctuation mark.

This tag might need to be disambiguated, since it is about more than one topic. There is also [punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) tag for questions about punctuation marks.

Comment: *"Full stop for the [period] tag"*?